# VueJs - Passing query in query string as prop

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm having an issue getting the URL query string from within a component. I am trying to implement this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode so I can pass the query as a prop. I haven't used query strings much, and I tend to use params, but I need the query string in this case. The problem I am having is `mounted()` doesn't seem to have access to the query.

Below is a basic sample of what I can't get working:

URL = `http://localhost:8080/?q=This%20is%20my%20query`

Router.js

```
{
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('./App.vue'),
    props: (route) => ({ query: route.query.q })
}
```

App.vue (Excerpt)

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        1.{{ $route.query }}
        2.{{ query }}
        <searchResults class="results"/>
    </div>
</template>

props: ['query'],
mounted () {
    console.log(this.query)
    console.log(this.$route.query)
},
```

In the code above, the following happens on visiting the URL in question:

`console.log(this.query) = undefined`

`console.log(this.$route.query) = undefined`

In the template, the following is output:

```
1.{}
2.
```

What do I need to do to get the query passed as the prop correctly?

Comment: Is using query string as prop actually necessary? I mean, isn't that enough to access the query string plainly as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35916241/5775077)?

Comment: Yes true, but I have had issues with that as well as detailed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201770/vuejs-route-not-available-on-page-load so I thought passing it as a prop might help

Comment: Did you try within other lifecyle hooks than mounted (or maybe in mounted, but wrapped within nextTick)?

Comment: Yes, I tried mounted and created.

Comment: Here's a demo of vue-router's props-function: https://codesandbox.io/s/yv5410xlmz

Comment: `component: () => require('./App.vue'),` shouldn't work. `require()` should be `import()` there. Is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: Yes copy paste error. My code is more or less exactly the same as the sandbox demo @tony19 supplied. Yet, I still get undefined?

Comment: `App.vue` is normally the root component. Why are you importing it dynamically?

Comment: Why do you use "q" as parameter if the prop is called "query"?