# VueJs - $route not available on page load

Tags: vue.js

I seem to have an issue with Vue, I'm running it vie Vue UI which is handling the compiling. I'm trying to solve an issue I have [VueJs - Passing query in query string as prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200983/vuejs-passing-query-in-query-string-as-prop) but I have noticed the below and I am not sure why.

URL = `http://localhost:8080/?q=This%20is%20my%20query`

```
mounted () {
    console.log(this.$route.query.q)
    console.log(this.$route.query)
}
```

Given the above url and the console.log the below outputs are happening. I can't figure out why the results are not the same

First visit to the url

```
undefined
Object {  }
```

After recompile and Vue UI hotreloads

```
This is my query
Object { q: "This is my query" }
```

Why can't I see `this.$route` on the first load?

Comment: Where exactly do those console.logs occur?

Comment: Sorry, edited question to show that they are running in the `mounted()` function

Comment: I can't reproduce it for some reason. I used vue-cli generated project, added the logs, opened Home, appended the same query string you have, and I see the `q` in the logs.

Comment: This is a Vue CLI generated project as well. After some digging `App.vue` which is loaded in the initial `new Vue({})` is where the problem lies. `App.vue`'s components can access the `$route` without issue