# Read URL query param values (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, callback, url-parameters

In vuejs callback URL I've some parameter value and I need to read this param value.  For example the return url is:  `http://localhost:8080/#/sucesspage?encryteddata=abdeshfkkilkalidfel&9a`

I have tried `this.$route.query.encryteddata` but I'm got null value.

Is there any way to get the param value in vuejs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should understand that Route Queries and Route Params in Vue are 2 different things. You declare Route params in your Router for example `www.example.com/30` = `/:id`, then you can get that data via `this.$route.params.id`

The Url Queries usually look like `www.example.com/hello?visible=false` and you can grab those with

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let myParam = urlParams.get('visible');
```

You can also combine these 2: for example getting on the Article with the ID of `30` while having a query telling you some other additional info. `/30?visible=false`