# Vue.js: Get Query String Parameter Values from URL

Tags: vue.js

I have the url `http://localhost:8058/HTML/Int/Request.html?id=36` from which I need to get the value `36`.when I used this `console.log(this.$route.query.id)`, I'm getting below error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined"

Comment: please add vue-router configuration

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below stack overflow link to fetch query parameters in Vue.js:

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914069/how-can-i-get-query-parameters-from-a-url-in-vue-js)