# How to get query params in Vue.js 3 setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to make search page which after I click its button will be redirected to another page. And this page will be like this

```
http://localhost:8080/search?q=foo
```

and my router `index.js` looks like this

```
const routers = [
  {
    path: '/search',
    name: 'Search',
    component: SearchPage,
    props: route => ( { query: route.query.q } )
  }
]
```

and the question is how do i get the query value in target page `SearchPage`, in Vue.js 3?
This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914069/how-can-i-get-query-parameters-from-a-url-in-vue-js) is still confusing me, because not using composition API and not in vuejs 3

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Using [`useRoute`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute)

You don't need to send the query as a prop. It's better to use [`useRoute`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute) because it's simpler and it can be accessed from any component, not just the page view component.

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    console.log(route.query);
  }
}
```

### Using a prop *(Not recommended)*

First change the router mapping so that `query` maps to the `query` object:

```js
props: route => ({ query: route.query })
```

In the destination component, `SearchPage`, create a `query` prop which will receive the `query` object from the router:

```
props: ['query']
```

And access it in `setup` via the `props` argument:

```js
props: ['query'],
setup(props) {
  console.log(props.query.q);
  console.log(props.query.status);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

another setup you can try, send propname by url
`{ path: '/search/:propname', name: 'Search', component: SearchPage, props: true },`
and on searchpage, on created() you can get recive it
 `this.$route.params.propname`

Comment: Sorry, but thats not what i want. i need to use query params pattern, not slug

Comment: I think this might come in handy one day, just not today.

Answer (score 0):

**For Vue Router 4** :: **Compositon API** :: **Vue3**

Router-link attach params

```
 <router-link
    style="width: 100%"
    class="btn btn-success btn-block edit"
    :to="{ name: 'editUser',params: {id: user.id}}">
       <i class="fa-solid fa-user-gear"></i>
 </router-link>
```

In a page you are receiving,

```
<script>

export default {
  props: ["id"],
  setup(props, context) {
        console.log(props.id);
  },
};
</script>
```

In Your app.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
...
...
const app = createApp(root);

app.use(router);

router.isReady().then(() => {
    app.mount('#app');
})
```