# Vue-router using params mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is it possible to use Vue router with such urls?

```
first page - /index.html?mode=api&tab=program
second page - /index.html?mode=api&tab=users
third page - /index.html?mode=api&tab=contact
etc.....
```

As you can see the changes only in params "tab".
Depending on that you will see the page. I can't find such example.

Comment: sure, make a route with path called `index.html`, then use `this.$route.query.mode` or `this.$route.query.tab` to get the params, and perhaps add a watch'er for each inside the page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query parameters from a URL in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914069/how-can-i-get-query-parameters-from-a-url-in-vue-js)