# Checking for a number in the url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
 if(window.location.href.includes('part_category_tags[]=2')) {
   this.checkedCategories.push(2);
 }
```

Needed: depending on what the number is next to the `part_category_tags[]=` parameter, push this number into the array.
also, it may be that such a parameter occurs twice like (Or not be at all):

```
&part_category_tags[]=3&part_category_tags[]=2
```

Without vue-router

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914069/how-can-i-get-query-parameters-from-a-url-in-vue-js

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the params.

```js
const url = new URL('https://fake.domain.name/?fake=query&part_category_tags[]=3&part_category_tags[]=2'); // document.location instead of fake utl.

let params = url.searchParams;

params.forEach((v,q) => console.info(q, v)); // just output queries and values

params.forEach((v,q) => { if (q === 'part_category_tags[]' && v === '2') { console.info('Pushing the 2') } });
// params.forEach((v,q) => { if (q === 'part_category_tags[]' && v === '2') { this.checkedCategories.push(v); } });
```

> Updated with numberless code.

```js
// // use document.location instead of fake url.
const url = new URL('https://fake.domain.name/?fake=query&part_category_tags=3&part_category_tags=2');

let params = url.searchParams;

params.forEach((v,q) => { if (q === 'part_category_tags') { console.info(`Pushing the ${v}`) } });
// params.forEach((v,q) => { if (q === 'part_category_tags') { this.checkedCategories.push(v); } });
```

Comment: Note that the `[]` arn't really necessary in the url and in the if statement, for it work.

Comment: As I said, I don't know what the number will be after ```part_category_tags```, I just need to push the number that will be. Is it possible to improve your code in this direction?

Comment: You should have been able to figure that one out from the code, but sure, I've added a example with no `int` restriction.