# Redirect url to VueJs SPA

Tags: vue.js, redirect, token

I am having a scenario, where we have a common login page for all our services. Currently, we are redirecting to different websites, based on the user at the login.

I have developed a SPA website in vue for one of our client and I need to redirect to the site from the above login service. The service redirects with a token and id in the url as parameters and based on those params, I need to authenticate in my web page. But my problem is, how the Vue js can get this url as BASEURL? As in when url looks like https://clientsite.ca/?token=************&id=**** how to get to the home page from there and validate token and id ?

Please help me

Comment: Consider explaining further, with more specific examples and code. It's unclear what exactly is the problem that you describe, the wording is not precise

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914069/how-can-i-get-query-parameters-from-a-url-in-vue-js